# How can I achieve an automatic icon update on the dock panel?

Tags: kubuntu, icons, plasma-5

I wrote a small bash script under Kubuntu 22.04 that establishes a VPN connection if not already available. It is started via Cron. As a small highlight, the Schript sets a .desktop file in

```
~/.local/share/plasma_icons
```

if the VPN location changes. Accordingly, the respective national flag of the VPN location appears on the dock panel to the right of the clock. Everything works well, only that this icon does not update itself when changed.

Now,

```
killall plasmashell ; sleep 1 ; kshell5 plasmashell
```

will restart the plasma build-up, but this process is very error-prone and should only be mentioned in an emergency.

How can I still achieve that the update is implemented immediately?
I am happy about any advice.

Comment: If you need help improving or adding additional functionality to a script that you wrote, you need to share the script! Please edit your question and make sure you've added enough information so that someone can answer your question.